# Mongo replica set `rs.add()` makes initial primary secondary and renders primary `fatal`

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I can't for the life of me I can't get a >1 member replica setup.  I get a single primary started what seems to be correctly:

```
sb-rs:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "sb-rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-09-16T22:38:53Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "primary-hostname:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 1213,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1410904778, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-09-16T21:59:38Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Then I start my secondary with:

> mongod --config /etc/mongo.conf --replSet sb-rs

The child process started successfully, parent exiting

and then from the primary I did:

```
sb-rs:PRIMARY> rs.add({_id: 1, host: "secondary-ip:27017", priority: 0, hidden: true})
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Then I got this:

```
sb-rs:PRIMARY> rs.status()
Tue Sep 16 15:41:30.226 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Sep 16 15:41:30.228 Error: error doing query: failed at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
Tue Sep 16 15:41:30.228 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Sep 16 15:41:30.229 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 ok
sb-rs:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "sb-rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-09-16T22:41:37Z"),
    "myState" : 4,
    "syncingTo" : "173.255.210.15:27017",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "primary-hostname:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 4,
            "stateStr" : "FATAL",
            "uptime" : 1377,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1410907283, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-09-16T22:41:23Z"),
            "errmsg" : "rollback error: not willing to roll back more than 30 minutes of data",
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "secondary-ip:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 14,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1410848803, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-09-16T06:26:43Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-09-16T22:41:36Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 71
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Can someone help me out with what I'm doing wrong or what I may be missing?

Comment: Can you post your confiuration file. or what does rs.conf() print out? Are you setting up the nodes in a single machine?

Comment: The `rs.conf` was the default one - whatever is setup after `rs.initiate()`.  I will stop and restart the server tomorrow to get the actual output, but it was basic host meta-data.  It would simply return the _id, and hostname, I believe.  The nodes are on separate machines.  I also tried `var cfg = rs.conf(); cfg.members[0].priority = 1; cfg.members[1].priority = 0` too to override the mongo behavior where it makes the initial primary a fatal secondary.

Comment: One thought I have is that because I'm using only two servers, instead of three, Mongo doesn't like that.  And if this is the case, that will be disappointing because I didn't want to have to use more than the primary + secondary + backup for this.  Anything more would be overkill IMO right now.

Comment: Have a look at "errmsg". There was a problem with a rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a lot to go on, but the fact that you are getting a [rollback](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) error suggests that the secondary node you are adding already has data in its `oplog`, it seems to already have a replica set config, and the data it contains is then triggering a rollback.  This might be a legacy of previous usage, or just an accident, but it seems to believe it is already a member of the set rather than joining a new set and doing an initial sync as would be expected.

I would recommend wiping the secondary completely (delete its data files) before adding it to the set (assuming you do not need the data on it, of course), and don't specify the full document (`_id`, priority etc.) when adding it, just do `rs.add("secondary-ip:27017")` to keep things simple. Once it is added you can then make it priority 0 and hidden - for now specifying the full config document just adds another variable in terms of what might be going wrong.

When adding it to the set watch the logs on the secondary to make sure it is doing an initial sync when it joins the set - if it fails after doing that then it would be best to post the logs to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I'll try this.  I had tried `priority: 0` to hopefully not make it a higher priority than the primary.

Comment: Clearing out the secondary's old rs/oplog files worked.  I cleared out ever possible file in the `LOCAL` database.  It's obviously important that one empties the local database and not a data containing database.  Also, my primary hostname was unresolvable on the primary so went with the IP instead (why do we use hostnames when IPs always work?).

Comment: Because IP addresses are likely to change in a lot of environments (like Amazon EC2 for example).  Hostnames can remain the same and simply be remapped.  This is particularly important for config servers in sharded environments (for example).  I would always recommend hostnames over IP Addresses generally.  As for the data - this is intended to be a replica of the primary, all its data should be identical to the primary, so there should be no data that you are keeping when a node joins a set, it should start from blank and sync from an existing node.